# Use SnapHelper to Scroll to a Child view in a recyclerview item

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

In my recyclerview onCreateViewholder method I create a dynamic which would have unspecified number of text views inside a linear layout

```
 if (sessionManager.getBookScrolOrientation() == AppConstents.HORIZONTAL) {
        LinearLayout linearLayout = new LinearLayout(context);
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT , ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
        linearLayout.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
        linearLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);

        Spannable spannable = getVerseSpanableHorizontal(pidreference.get(position) , cidreference.get(position));

        Pagination pagination =  new Pagination(spannable,
                pageWidth,
                pageHight,
                textPaint,
               lineSpacingMultiplier,
               lineSpacingExtra,
                isTextPaddingIncluded);

        List<CharSequence> list = pagination.getPages();

        for (CharSequence charSequence : list){
            TextView tv = new TextView(linearLayout.getContext());
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(Tools.getScreenWidth() , ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
            tv.setLayoutParams(params);
            tv.setText(charSequence);

            linearLayout.addView(tv);
        }


        MainViewHolder viewHolder = new MainViewHolder(linearLayout);


        return viewHolder;





    }
```

When i use SnapHelper with this recyclerview it scrolls to the center of linear layout not the next textview. How can i make it scroll to the next textview inside the linearlayout?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, the problem is that `SnapHelper` snaps the center of the current view to the center of the recycler. As the [docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/LinearSnapHelper.html) say:

> The implementation will snap the center of the target child view to the center of the attached RecyclerView.

If you want the the current view to snap to the start of the recycler use a libraray such as this [one](https://github.com/DevExchanges/SnappingRecyclerview). Import it with gradle and activate it like this:

```
GravitySnapHelper(Gravity.START).attachToRecyclerView(recyclerview);
```